# StringBuilder remove comma at the end of Last record

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am using StringBuilder to show comma between records, but also getting comma at the end of Last Record

How to control on this ? I don't like to see comma at the end of last record - because it's useless

```
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

        String name = arrayList.get(i).getName();
        int price = arrayList.get(i).getPrice();

        stringBuilder.append(strName);
        stringBuilder.append(" - "+price+",");

    }

        stringFinal = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Either subString the String returned or call `deleteCharAt(...)`  passing in StringBuilder length - 1.

Comment: how about if (i == arrayList.size () -1) omit the comma

Comment: Consider [`String::join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

Comment: Any specific reason you want to remove it after adding? Why not prevent it being added for the last item itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a check for the last item.

```
if (i < arrayList.size() - 1) {
  stringBuilder.append(" - "+price+",");
} else {
  stringBuilder.append(" - "+price);
}
```

or:

```
stringBuilder.append(" - "+price);
if (i < arrayList.size() - 1) {
  stringBuilder.append(",");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

## Java 8 Solution

You don't need any check when using Java 8. All you need is to use `StringJoiner` (or `String.join()`).

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    String name = arrayList.get(i).getName();
    int price = arrayList.get(i).getPrice();

    joiner.add(strName + " - " + price);
}
String joinedString = joiner.toString();
```

And you can make it even cleaner by taking advantage of the `Stream` API (thanks to @Sasha):

```
String joinedString = String.join(",", list.stream().map(
        e -> e.getName() + " - " + e.getPrice()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete the last character:

```
 stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length()-1);
 stringFinal = stringBuilder.toString();
```

that would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = stringBuilder.lastIndexOf(",");
if (index != -1){
    stringBuilder.replace(index, index+1, "");
}
String stringFinal = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or loop till size - 1 and then add the last element after wards without a comma.

```
int i = 0, price = 0;
String name = null;
for (i = 0; i < arrayList.size() - 1; i++) {
 name = arrayList.get(i).getName();
 price = arrayList.get(i).getPrice();

 stringBuilder.append(strName);
 stringBuilder.append(" - "+price+",");
}

name = arrayList.get(i).getName();
price = arrayList.get(i).getPrice();
stringBuilder.append(strName);
stringBuilder.append(" - "+price);
stringFinal = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

    String name = arrayList.get(i).getName();
    int price = arrayList.get(i).getPrice();

    stringBuilder.append(strName);
    if(i== arrayList.size()-1)
       stringBuilder.append(" - "+price);
    else
    stringBuilder.append(" - "+price+",");

     }

    stringFinal = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing it in last you can write it in front like :-

```
        String name = arrayList.get(0).getName();
        int price = arrayList.get(0).getPrice();

        stringBuilder.append(strName).append(" - "+price);
for (int i = 1; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

        name = arrayList.get(i).getName();
        price = arrayList.get(i).getPrice();

        stringBuilder.append(","+strName).append(" - "+price);

    }

        stringFinal = stringBuilder.toString();
```